# I have a function that empties a div, but I want it to ignore some elements?

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
function clearSlides(){

    var myNode = document.getElementById("modal_content");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild); 
    }
  }
```

This is my code for a function that deletes all of the inner elements within #modal_content. But I need it to ignore elements that have a certain class (whatever that class may be). For example if I have 3 elements with classes .a .b and .c I'd want it to delete everything except the these elements. But I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearSlides(){

    var myNode = document.getElementById("modal_content");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild).not(".Classname .Classname .Classname"); 
    }
  }
```

Didn't try it

Comment: I'll test it out and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Use [**remove**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method instead of empty.Also using spread operator to convert nodelist to array

```js
function clearSlides() {
  var myNode = document.getElementById("modal_content");
  //use spread operator to convert nodelist to array for using
  // array methods
  var c = [...myNode.children];
  c.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item)
    // check if the current element have a class using 'contains'
    if (!item.classList.contains('a')) {
      //use remove method to remove the element
      item.remove();
    }
  })

}
clearSlides()
```

```html
<div id="modal_content">
  <span class="a"> Have class a</span>
  <span> No CLass</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the "..." In var c mean?

Comment: Also if I wanted it to not remove a few different elements with different classes, ie don't remove ones with class a b or c, how would I do that?